# Animate scrollleft working good with ('html, body') but gives undesired results with ('#div')

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WuhW9/) that's working good but i actually want to scroll only a div and not the whole body.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rEzEE/) that i tried but it is giving undesired results.
changed the offset() to position() but same result.

HTML code:

```
    <ul id="banner">
        <li> <a href="#1">1</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#2">2</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#3">3</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#4">4</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
            <div id="1" class="panel">1</div>
            <div id="2" class="panel">2</div>
            <div id="3" class="panel">3</div>
            <div id="4" class="panel">4</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
body {

    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.panel {
    width: 25%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 45px;

}
ul#banner {
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin: 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}
ul#banner li {
    display: inline;
    z-index: 10;
}

#container {

    width: 400%;

}

#wrapper { width: 100%; overflow-x:hidden; }
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#banner a").bind("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        $(" #wrapper").stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left,
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly there

You need to animate your container not your wrapper, and the wrapper needs to have `position:relative` in its css

```
#wrapper { width: 100%; overflow-x:hidden; position:relative;}
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#banner a").bind("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#container").stop().animate({
            left: $(target).offset().left,
            top: $(target).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rEzEE/2/)

Comment: Tried it but its not working. :( Did that fiddle work for you?

Comment: Sorry the #container div is the one that needs `position:relative`, updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rEzEE/3/)

Comment: Thanks for that. It's working. BTW I found another way to do it by just changing `scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left` to `scrollLeft: $(target).position().left - $("#container").position().left`. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KczeK/1/).